# C# BackgroundWorker is not reporting progress

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The Background worker in my app does not report progress.  (A breakpoint is set, but it is never reached).  The code I'm using is attached below.  I've been working on this for a couple hours and I'm stumped.  The 'usual suspects' (setting the boolean for WorkerReportsProgress, and Linking the event to _ProgressChanged, forgetting to call .RunWorkerAsyn() have been checked) I'm puzzled why my breakpoint is never reached.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker bw_copyToTemp;  //Defined as a member of the class

    private void btnCopyToTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       bw_copyToTemp = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
       {
           WorkerReportsProgress = true,
           WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
       };
       bw_copyToTemp.DoWork += bw_copyToTemp_DoWork;
       bw_copyToTemp.ProgressChanged += bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged;
       bw_copyToTemp.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_copyToTemp_RunWorkerCompleted;


       // Start background worker
       bw_copyToTemp.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged(object sender,System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentState s = (CurrentState)e.UserState;  //<<BREAKPOINT HERE NOT HIT
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = s.ProcessStep;
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void bw_copyToTemp_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        Properties.Settings prop = Properties.Settings.Default;
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if (worker.WorkerReportsProgress)
            // Initialize the object that the background worker calls.
            worker.ReportProgress(0, new CurrentState("Called from within form"));  //<<< THIS LINE IS PROCESSED SINGLE STEPPING THROUGH CODE (NO CHANGE IN GUI)

        copyFileOnDVDToTemp.CopyOpticalToHardDrive(worker, e);


    }

    void bw_copyToTemp_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // test code goes here
    }
}
```

The "Current state" class is in a different .cs file with the same namespace:

```
   public class CurrentState
        {
            public CurrentState() { }
            public CurrentState(string processStep)
            {
                this.ProcessStep = processStep;
            }

            public string ProcessStep { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: Can you please correct the code sample? The third method has no method name but I guess it is the `bw_copyToTemp_RunWorkerCompleted` method.

Comment: Thanks.  Code sample has been corrected

Comment: You have removed the `bw_copyToTemp_RunWorkerCompleted` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed to call [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in the Click event handler of the button. Your worker does not get started after initialization.

```
private void btnCopyToTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   bw_copyToTemp = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
   {
       WorkerReportsProgress = true,
       WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
   };
   bw_copyToTemp.DoWork += bw_copyToTemp_DoWork;
   bw_copyToTemp.ProgressChanged += bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged;
   bw_copyToTemp.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_copyToTemp_RunWorkerCompleted;

   // Start background worker
   bw_copyToTemp.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Try the following to see that `ReportProgress` is called while `DoWork` is running:

```
    void bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set breakpoint here
        CurrentState s = (CurrentState)e.UserState; 
    }

    void bw_copyToTemp_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            // Set breakpoint here
            worker.ReportProgress(i, new CurrentState("Percentage"));
        }
    }
```

Debug your application and see how the breakpoints get hit.

Comment: I tried to delete extraneous lines from the SO post and inadvertently deleted the .RunWorkerAsync() line.  I have edited my post.  There is a comment in the _dowork method that shows the line that executes but does not update the GUI.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the beginning of `bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged` method - it should get hit when progress is reported.

Comment: I have edited the original post (again).  Several lines of the bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged method were duplicated.  The breakpoint in the bw_copyToTemp_ProgressChanged is never reached.

Comment: I built a VS project and tried the code sample. The breakpoint gets hit and the worker reports the progress as expected. Your real code must be different to the code above.

Comment: I will have to review the rest of the code - probably this weekend.  Thanks for taking the time to build a project to test it Oliver.

Comment: I commented everything out except for the code that was posted here in SO and IT WORKED FINE.  However the breakpoint for _progressChanged was not hit until AFTER the _DoWork method completed.  The next line in my code is a "copyOpticalDVDFilesToTemp.CopyOpticalToHardDrive(worker, e);"(I've pasted that into the original example)  Is there a way to force _ProgressUpdate to run during the _DoWork Method?

Comment: `ProgressChanged` event is raised while `DoWork` is running. The observed behavior is caused by threading. I edited my post with a sample to show that it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm checking your post as the answer.